# how to resize an image on a page to a percentage of the page width

Tags: html, css

Like in the subject I don't know how to set width of an image on a page ot a percentage of page width. I mean something like this.
`img {width: calc(width-page*16.5%);}`

Comment: Do you mean page width or viewport width? Also could you include enough code for us to be able to see your HTML structure?

Comment: I mean viewport width. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Seeting the width to say 15vw will set it to 15% of the viewport width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's viewport then vw (stands for viewport width)